# Python QT logging on QTextEdit and file on different levels

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a small GUI application that has a logging text area, and I'm trying to make another level of logging goes to a file.

I would like to send DEBUG logs to the QTextEdit, and ERROR logs to the file.

The ERROR logs are successfully filtered and passed to the file.

However, the QTextEdit is capturing all logs regardless of their level.

How can i send only DEBUG logs to the QTextEdit?

Thanks for your help in advance!

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebSockets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from dashboard import MainApp
import logging
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

def setup_logging():
    logging.basicConfig(
        level = logging.DEBUG, 
        format = '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
        datefmt ='%H:%M:%S'          
    )

    logger = logging.getLogger("mylog")
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s | %(name)s |  %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    logFilePath = "my.log"
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=logFilePath)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainapp = MainApp()
    setup_logging()
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(mainapp.logger)

    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s | %(name)s |  %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

    logFilePath = "my.log"

    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=logFilePath)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(file_handler)
    mainapp.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

dashboard.py

```
class QTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):

    class Signal(QObject):
        signal_log_append = pyqtSignal(str)
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super().__init__(parent=parent)
    

    def __init__(self, parent:QTextEdit):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = parent
        self.widget.setReadOnly(True)
        self.signal = self.Signal(None)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.signal.signal_log_append.emit(msg)

class MainApp(QMainWindow):
    self.logger = QTextEditLogger(self.ui.text_log)
    self.logger.signal.signal_log_append.connect(self.log)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `logging.getLogger('mylog').addHandler(mainapp.logger)`?

Comment: @musicamante i already tried that without luck

Comment: Then please provide a valid [mre], and also try to tidy up your code, as those overlapped calls to logging objects are very confusing (and probably the reason for the issue).

Comment: @musicamante thanks for the heads-up about the overlapped calls! Will look them over and see what happens. I'll also try to provide an MRE as soon as possible.